# ActiveResource reporting connection refused but Apache Logs Indicate authorization granted

Tags: php, drupal-7, activeresource

I'm using Redmine as a support ticketing system and have created a form in my Drupal implementation to create an issue in Redmine using ActiveResource.php.  The code works in PHPStorm, and also in a ProcessMaker installation, so I know that it works fine in most environments.

When the PHP runs, the instance of issue is created properly, but when save is executed I get the error reported within the instance "Failed to connect to .com port 443: Connection refused" and the issue is not created.  When I check the Apache error.log, though, I see that the referring URL (from Drupal) was granted authorization.

I'm assuming its something a bit odd about Drupal, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I should add that I'm using an api access key instead of standard authentication.

Comment: Are you always using HTTPS to connect to Redmine?

Comment: Yes.  I have mod_rewrite setup to redirect http traffic to https as well.